# Get the like count of a facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made the following function to get the like count of a public post. But facebook seems to have changed something, since it's only returning JSON without actually any data in it.

```
static function getFBPostLikes($url){
    $id = self::getFbIdFromUrl($url);
    $json = self::readJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/likes?limit=10000000");
    return count($json['data']);
}
```

It used to include every like of the post, which I was able to count. I just set the limit parameter very high, because the default value is something like 50.

Any idea how to solve this problem with the recent changes?

Comment: you need to pass a valid access token, to the graph api request

Comment: that wasn't needed before

Comment: I only used that method since it seemed to be the only public-working-one

Comment: but now it is, to prevent random requests to fetch data

Comment: Will I need the user's tokens or is the new request semi-public where I only need an app?

Comment: using your ID create an app token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Comment: or create tokens on behalf of the users I don't know the purpose of your app. If you just want to query public information, the app token is fine

Comment: I'll be able to test that in ~10hours, but thanks so far :)